# Как можно прочитать первые несколько байт файла не дожидаясь полной загрузки на php сервер и если что - все отменить

Tags: php, imagemagick

Задача такая что файл слишком большой и я бы не хотел ждать окончания загрузки на сервер и отсекать их сразу если файлы не валидны

на сервере php. который загружает файл во временную папку и лишь потом работает с ним (валидация только после окончания загрузки файла полностью)

Comment: Нашел такое https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php Скрытое поле MAX_FILE_SIZE (значение необходимо указывать в байтах) должно предшествовать полю для выбора файла, и его значение является максимально допустимым размером принимаемого файла в PHP. Рекомендуется всегда использовать эту переменную, так как она предотвращает тревожное ожидание пользователей при передаче огромных файлов, только для того, чтобы узнать, что файл слишком большой и передача фактически не состоялась. НО ЭТО НЕМНОГО НЕ ТО

Comment: Мне нужно проверить не только размер файла